# Repeatedly missing Microsoft Office references in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, ms-access, reference

An Access database used by multiple people at my office occasionally flashes several error messages in quick succession and then loses some macro functionality. The first time it happened, I researched the topic and found a solution - there were missing references in Visual Basic that had to be fixed. Upon opening the reference list, 4 that were selected all read 'MISSING: Microsoft X 16.0 Object Library' where X is [Word, Powerpoint, Excel, Outlook]. I deselected these references, scrolled down and selected the 15.0 Object Library references. Things were back to normal, full macro functionality restored.

However, the references keep reverting back to 16.0 Object Library ones that are still missing. Sometimes it will be several weeks before I have to replace the missing references with the older version, sometimes it will happen the next day. It's not a difficult fix at all, but it keeps happening, and most of the other users would not know what to do.

I have to imagine the problem is persisting because the database is shared across multiple computers in the same office, though I believe all PCs have the same version of Microsoft Office installed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what you believe, I suspect that someone has a newer version of Office, perhaps Access 2016 or an Office 365 subscription.  I experience this problem at my office, but it is expected since I know that some computers have Access 2016 while I am using Office 2013.

Creating a separate front-end database is already a best practice for many reason.  It would likely eliminate or reduce such problems with your shared database.  The shared back-end database can be stripped of all code modules and macros that might be dependent on a particular version.  The front-end can then be copied to each client.  As long as the front-end database is distributed (i.e. copied) from a lesser version (i.e. references last set to Office 15.0 for example) to each client, any newer versions of Access will automatically update the references of only its local copy.

Comment: Even if all the office computers have the same version, perhaps someone is using a laptop / mobile device with a different version.

Comment: I didn't think about possible laptop use, but that very well could be the case. I'll have to ask our IT division. As for the front-end/back-end situation, I think that could be implemented. We have a much larger database that operates that way, and the reference issues do not come up in that one. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a very annoying feature of Microsoft's Component Object Model. (Although it was extremely cutting edge when it was revealed to us in the mid 1990s.)

A practical solution is to switch the VBA to use late binding rather than early binding. In doing that you can drop the explicit reference altogether and the problem goes away.

A half way house is to use a late binding loader addin which, depending on the client configuration, loads an addin specific to their environment. That loaded addin can use early binding.

The second option might be more practical in that it would require fewer code changes.

Comment: Could you share a resource (link) how to do this?  I'm familiar with late binding for particular objects and that is all I find reference to online.  Is there a way to establish late binding for the global references in the VBE so all VBA modules don't have to be updated/tweaked?  From what I understand once a VBE reference is set using code, it is automatically saved and so would persist and cause the same problem when the database is opened again in Access.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I'll look into late binding, but this was a database that I inherited. It works decently for what it is supposed to do, but the code behind it is not nearly as organized as my CS classes would have me believe. I suppose I'll have to get used to that in the real world... Thanks again.